# tmux session lost in unknown pts, cause and possible solution?

Tags: process, tmux, session

I was trying to re-attach to a long-running tmux session to check up on a python web-application. However `tmux attach` claims that there is no running session, and `ps` shows a `tmux` process (first line), but with a question mark instead of the `pts` number.

What does this mean---is this tmux session permanently lost, and what could have caused it? Is there still a way to look at the current state of the python process, spawned in the tmux session and running in `pts/19` (second line)?

```
[mhermans@web314 ~]$ ps -ef | grep mhermans
mhermans 16709     1  0 Mar04 ?        00:26:32 tmux
mhermans  8526 16710  0 Mar04 pts/19   00:20:04 python2.7 webapp.py
root      9985  6671  0 10:18 ?        00:00:00 sshd: mhermans [priv]
mhermans 10028  9985  0 10:18 ?        00:00:00 sshd: mhermans@pts/16
mhermans 10030 10028  0 10:18 pts/16   00:00:00 -bash
mhermans 16247 10030  6 10:28 pts/16   00:00:00 ps -ef
mhermans 16276 10030  0 10:28 pts/16   00:00:00 grep mhermans
mhermans 16710 16709  0 Mar04 pts/19   00:00:00 -bash
mhermans 16777 16709  0 Mar04 pts/21   00:00:00 -bash
```

Comment: What does `tmux ls` show?

Comment: "failed to connect to server: Connection refused"

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Solution courtesy of the [Webfaction-support](http://community.webfaction.com/questions/9462/tmux-session-lost-in-unknown-pts-cause-and-possible-solution):

As the process was still running, the issue was a deleted socket, possibly caused by a purged tmp-directory.

According to the `tmux` mapage:

> If the socket is accidentally removed, the SIGUSR1 signal may be sent to the tmux server process to recreate it.

So sending the signal and attaching works:

```
killall -s SIGUSR1 tmux
tmux attach
```

Comment: I am using `byobu`, which uses `tmux` as a backend, and this worked for me after I accidentally deleted the socket from `/tmp/tmux-<pid>`. Thanks!

Comment: if you know the PID of tmux process, you can use `kill -10 <PID>` or `kill -SIGUSR1 <PID>` as  -SIGUSR1 is -10 . This is useful when you are on a shared server. You don't want to send SIGUSR1 to other users' tmux processes.

Comment: You can also use `pkill -10 tmux` to directly send `SIGUSR1` to all tmux process

Comment: @itamarkanter thank you! Your version worked for me

Answer (score 10):

Terminal absence is a sign of detached session. And all your `tmux` session names can be found thus:

`ls $TMP/tmux-$(id -u)` or `ls /var/run/tmux/tmux-$(id -u)`

— this is kinda distro-dependent. Almost distro-independent (and more hardcore) would be:

`lsof -n -p 16709 -a -U`

where `16709` is the PID of tmux in your listing.

Comment: `id -u` gives `532` and `/tmp/tmux-532` contains a single file "default". How does this help me further?

Comment: Try `tmux -S /tmp/tmux-532/default at`, but default socket-name should be just ok with `tmux at`. What does `lsof`-version say?

Comment: The first command results in a "no sessions" response. `lsof -v` [output](http://pastie.org/4105235).

Comment: `lsof` as given in my answer, dude. :)

Comment: @mhermans, I meant lsof-version of my answer, we don't need its software version. :)

Comment: I misunderstood. See [output](http://pastie.org/4108425).

Comment: @mhermans, and where's `awk` part? )

Comment: @mhermans, also, it's rather too short. Can you manage to run lsof part with root creds? Don't forget to pipe through awk anyway. ;-)

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I don't understand what you are getting at. Why would the `awk` filter help if there are only four results?  In fact, the `awk` filter does not return a single hit on the complete `lsof` output. And in any case, I do not have root access.

Comment: @mhermans, 4 lines is what that exactly worries me.

Comment: @mhermans, if you'd like you may contact me (see profile for info).  It's strange case, so I'm interested a bit. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is how [this earlier answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40940/213273) helped me (wow!).  I was trying to resolve **exactly** the situation where I'm attached to one Tmux--which I can see in `tmux ls`, *but* in `ps`, I can see also *another* tmux, which is not listed in `tmux ls` therefore I cannot attach to it via using its name (`tmux attach -t myOldbas)`

Here are the full details. Processes:

```
71358     1849  9617  0 Sep04 pts/29   00:00:00 /bin/bash
71358     2528  9617  0 Aug31 pts/25   00:00:00 /bin/bash
71358     9617     1  0 Aug31 ?        00:08:55 tmux new -s myOld
71358     9618  9617  0 Aug31 pts/20   00:00:00 /bin/bash
71358    20199 33189  0 Sep16 pts/27   00:00:00 vim log
71358    20415 32257  0 Sep16 pts/30   00:00:00 /bin/bash
71358    24735 32257  0 Sep16 pts/33   00:00:00 /bin/bash
71358    32257     1  0 Sep16 ?        00:04:02 tmux new -s myses
```

Now, **the lsof bit is what really helped me**--when you do it for **both processes**, in my case 32257 (the one I can see), and 9617 (the old one)

```
/usr/sbin/lsof -n -p 32257 -a -U
COMMAND   PID             USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
..
tmux    32257 uzer.buzer          7u  unix 0xffff881ff0c73480      0t0 995795763 /tmp/uzer.buzer/tmux-71358/default
```

However when I used on the old PID , I saw the following

```
/usr/sbin/lsof -n -p 9617 -a -U

tmux    9617 uzer.buzer          7u  unix 0xffff881ff0c73480      0t0 995795763 /tmp/tmux-71358/default
```

Notice, *how the last socket path is different?*  Luckily, that's all I needed and then I executed the attach command with an explicit socket:

```
tmux -S /tmp/tmux-71358/default at
```

and I was in!!  Attached to my old tmux called `myOldbas`.
(In reality what probably happened earlier was that I was changing TMP paths/.bashrc and ended up with two tmux sessions)

Answer (score 0):

For people who come across this thread at a later date;

If you use `sudo` to run a script or something, the `tmux` session is listed under root, not under the user who used sudo, since actions following sudo are performed under root.

To remedy this, either use `sudo tmux a`, or `tmux` as root to regain control of your tmux session.