# How to attach to a tmux session after deleting it's session file?

Tags: tmux, session

`tmux` keeps track of active sessions in a file, on my system this is in `/tmp/tmux-1000/default`. Recently I manually cleared everything in the `/tmp` directory, removing this session file.

Normally, you can use `tmux attach` to reattach to a session. Active sessions can be listed using `tmux ls`. Because this file is gone, `tmux` doesn't know about any active sessions:

```
$ tmux attach
no sessions    
$ tmux ls
error connecting to /tmp/tmux-1000/default (No such file or directory)
```

Using `top` I can verify `tmux` is still running, along with the applications I had opened in that session.

How can I reattach to this session, after I've removed the session file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer was noted in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40928/tmux-session-lost-in-unknown-pts-cause-and-possible-solution) post.

Sending an `SIGUSR1` signal to the `tmux` process recreases the socket file, allowing you to reattach using `tmux attach` afterwards.

Since the PID of the running `tmux` command was `5612`, I used:

```bsh
$ sudo kill -SIGUSR1 5612
$ tmux attach
```